# Google Apps Script for converting military Timestamp into 12-Hr in Forms submissions?

Tags: google-sheets, google-apps-script, google-forms

Has anyone created a script to use in Google Forms/Sheets to convert or display the military time to 12-hour instead once the form has been submitted by a user?

Comment: I'd expect that formatting the cell(s) would be the solution, as the sheet doesn't store time in human-readable format anyway.

Answer (score 0):

OP has revisited and not bothered to respond to a request for clarification so I presume is not going to return. The solution may be to to format the cells appropriately, for example, if something like this:

[image: WA109305 first example]

with something like this:

[image: WA109305 second example]